# Bi-monthly Android traffic to a URL getting blocked

Tags: malware, android, smartphone

Last month, I reset my cell phone, also immediately installed Malwarebytes and Avast. Every scan until now was/is safe.

But I also have a virus scanner which is included in my ISP safety package (Telenet Safeguard - Not a lot is known, but it appears to be based on Bitdefender, although no settings or user info is really available (only very simple logs and 'on/off'))

Every 2 weeks (Sunday morning), Telenet Safeguard blocks 10 tries to browse to `columbus.shortest-route.com`. 10 is probably the retry count.

When googling this, it seems to be related to malware, but the indications are not that clear for me.

I checked my phone with multiple virus scanners (Malwarebytes, Avast, Bitdefender), but all scans are clear.

Is this something known? My cell phone is a Samsung device running Android.

And if not known, how can I check what process (or app) is doing this? Because it definitely isn't an action done by me on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Found it out myself. It appears to be related to mails coming from Procter & Gamble. When opening them, this 'browse attempt' is blocked.